# NSRunalertpanel

Tags: cocoa

I have an alert panel say,

```
NSRunAlertPanel(@"Alert!", @"Do you want to mail your team or raise a Request?", @"Mail", @"Cancel", @"Request");
```

If i click on the mail the mail window should be shown and if i click on request respective window should get opened. so i tried ,

```
    if (NSAlertDefaultReturn){
      [mailWindow showWindow:mailWindow];
    }

    if (NSAlertOtherReturn){
      [reqWindow showWindow:reqWindow];
    }
```

but i'm getting both the windows open when i click on 'request'. I'm new to coc

Answer (score 1):

try
NSInteger err = NSRunAlert...(x,x,x,x,x)
err is then value of button pressed - 1,2 or 3